# Polygamma sum problem

Tags: analysis, summation, special-functions, summation-method, polygamma

I have a problem evaluating the following sum,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{4nx(3\pi ^{2}(n+1)^{2}+x^{2})}{(x^{2}-\pi ^{2}(n+1)^{2})^{3}}$$
The sum obviously is of the form of a polygamma function. What i think is the right path is to do partial fractions and write it in the form $$\frac{4nx(3\pi ^{2}(n+1)^{2}+x^{2})}{(x^{2}-\pi ^{2}(n+1)^{2})^{3}}=\frac{A}{(x-\pi (n+1)))^{3}}+\frac{B}{(x+\pi (n+1))^{3}}$$ But funnily enough i have a problem finding what A and B are. Also im not 100% sure if this is the right way, but i think it is. Please help me if you can!

Comment: Just reduce to same denominator and identify comparing the powers of $x$. The result is more than simple.

Comment: There is so much, i mean, to compare i need to expand and solve the system....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Write
$$4nx(3\pi ^{2}(n+1)^{2}+x^{2})=A (x+\pi  (n+1))^3+B (x-\pi  (n+1))^3$$
Make $x=-\pi  (n+1)$ to get
$$-16 \pi ^3 n (n+1)^3=-8 \pi ^3  (n+1)^3 B$$ which does not look too difficult.

Do the same with $x=\pi  (n+1)$ to get $A$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the sum, was a lenghty process but it is what it is. I guess i can use this anytime i need to find constants, set one equal to that and get it and vice versa.

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic. It is not so long after the decomposition

Comment: Well, 6 terms of polygamma functions....Not so short ;P

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic. Not six but four.

Comment: Looks like both me and mathematica are wrong then.

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic. For the first summation, let $x=y+\pi$ and for the second $x=z-\pi$. Compute and go back to $x$.

Comment: I computed the summations and got correct for sure, as i checked the numericals values too.

Comment: Other methods are possible for sure.